# Order a group of transactions with multiple levels using FIFO?

Tags: sql-server, recursion, common-table-expression, fifo

I have a group of transactions with multiple levels that need to be ordered using FIFO. I don't have a typical parent child record set either. Transaction numbers are not sequenced, but each transaction has a "other transaction #" to relate it to any transactions that are transferred between accounts.

- A transfer is movement of units between accounts in the same fund.
- A switch is a switch of units between funds on the same account.

In order of levels, my transactions below:

The result I am looking for should have the same result set, but an additional column for "order" of transactions. The order needs to use FIFO based where the first transaction is number 1 and the order will follow transfers and switches in and out appropriately.

The challenge the order needs follow the transfers and switches down the whole hierarchy before moving to the next transaction in the same level.

Sample record set

```
CREATE TABLE #data (
  [Level] INT NOT NULL,
  FundId INT NOT NULL,
  AccountId INT NOT NULL,
  TransId VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
  OtherTransId VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  TransType VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  TransDate DATE NOT NULL,
  AgeDays INT NULL,
  Units INT NOT NULL
 );

INSERT #data VALUES 
(1,200,5000,'00000015','00000035','Switch In','2019-01-01',NULL,500),
(2,200,5000,'00000035','00000015','Switch Out','2019-01-01',NULL,500),
(2,200,5000,'00000070',NULL,'Buy','2018-09-09',452,700),
(2,200,5000,'00000046',NULL,'Sell','2018-09-12',449,200),
(1,100,5000,'00000001',NULL,'Buy','2019-06-30',159,100),
(1,100,5000,'00000002',NULL,'Sell','2019-07-15',NULL,20),
(1,100,5000,'00000003',NULL,'Buy','2019-07-31',128,50),
(1,100,5000,'00000004','00000011','Transfer Out','2019-08-15',NULL,45),
(2,100,6000,'00000005','00000020','Transfer In','2019-08-17',NULL,200),
(2,100,6000,'00000020','00000005','Transfer Out','2019-08-17',NULL,200),
(2,100,6000,'00000044',NULL,'Buy','2019-06-11',177,70),
(2,100,6000,'00000050','00000088','Transfer In','2019-06-10',NULL,130),
(3,100,7000,'00000088','00000050','Transfer Out','2019-06-10',NULL,130),
(3,100,7000,'00000079',NULL,'Buy','2019-06-01',187,130);

+-------+--------+-----------+---------------+---------------------+------------------+-----------------+------------+-------+
| Level | Fund # | Account # | Transaction # | Other Transaction # | Transaction Type |      Date       | Age (Days) | Units |
+-------+--------+-----------+---------------+---------------------+------------------+-----------------+------------+-------+
|     1 |    200 |      5000 |      00000015 |            00000035 | Switch In        | January 1, 2019 |            |   500 |
|     2 |    200 |      5000 |      00000035 |            00000015 | Switch Out       | January 1, 2019 |            |   500 |
|     2 |    200 |      5000 |      00000070 |                     | Buy              | Sept 9, 2018    |        452 |   700 |
|     2 |    200 |      5000 |      00000046 |                     | Sell             | Sept 12, 2018   |        449 |   200 |
|     1 |    100 |      5000 |      00000001 |                     | Buy              | June 30, 2019   |        159 |   100 |
|     1 |    100 |      5000 |      00000002 |                     | Sell             | July 15, 2019   |            |    20 |
|     1 |    100 |      5000 |      00000003 |                     | Buy              | July 31, 2019   |        128 |    50 |
|     1 |    100 |      5000 |      00000004 |            00000011 | Transfer Out     | August 15, 2019 |            |    45 |
|     2 |    100 |      6000 |      00000005 |            00000020 | Transfer In      | August 17, 2019 |            |   200 |
|     2 |    100 |      6000 |      00000020 |            00000005 | Transfer Out     | August 17, 2019 |            |   200 |
|     2 |    100 |      6000 |      00000044 |                     | Buy              | June 11, 2019   |        177 |    70 |
|     2 |    100 |      6000 |      00000050 |            00000088 | Transfer In      | June 10, 2019   |            |   130 |
|     3 |    100 |      7000 |      00000088 |            00000050 | Transfer Out     | June 10, 2019   |            |   130 |
|     3 |    100 |      7000 |      00000079 |                     | Buy              | June 1, 2019    |        187 |   130 |
+-------+--------+-----------+---------------+---------------------+------------------+-----------------+------------+-------+
```

Desired output: (added order column)

```
+-------+-------+--------+-----------+---------------+---------------------+------------------+-----------------+------------+-------+
| Order | Level | Fund # | Account # | Transaction # | Other Transaction # | Transaction Type |      Date       | Age (Days) | Units |
+-------+-------+--------+-----------+---------------+---------------------+------------------+-----------------+------------+-------+
|     1 |     1 |    200 |      5000 |      00000015 |            00000035 | Switch In        | January 1, 2019 |            |   500 |
|     2 |     2 |    200 |      5000 |      00000035 |            00000015 | Switch Out       | January 1, 2019 |            |   500 |
|     3 |     2 |    200 |      5000 |      00000070 |                     | Buy              | Sept 9, 2018    |        452 |   700 |
|     4 |     2 |    200 |      5000 |      00000046 |                     | Sell             | Sept 12, 2018   |        449 |   200 |
|     5 |     1 |    100 |      5000 |      00000001 |                     | Buy              | June 30, 2019   |        159 |   100 |
|     6 |     1 |    100 |      5000 |      00000002 |                     | Sell             | July 15, 2019   |            |    20 |
|     7 |     1 |    100 |      5000 |      00000003 |                     | Buy              | July 31, 2019   |        128 |    50 |
|     8 |     1 |    100 |      5000 |      00000004 |            00000011 | Transfer Out     | August 15, 2019 |            |    45 |
|     9 |     2 |    100 |      6000 |      00000005 |            00000020 | Transfer In      | August 17, 2019 |            |   200 |
|    10 |     2 |    100 |      6000 |      00000020 |            00000005 | Transfer Out     | August 17, 2019 |            |   200 |
|    11 |     2 |    100 |      6000 |      00000044 |                     | Buy              | June 11, 2019   |        177 |    70 |
|    12 |     2 |    100 |      6000 |      00000050 |            00000088 | Transfer In      | June 10, 2019   |            |   130 |
|    13 |     3 |    100 |      7000 |      00000088 |            00000050 | Transfer Out     | June 10, 2019   |            |   130 |
|    14 |     3 |    100 |      7000 |      00000079 |                     | Buy              | June 1, 2019    |        187 |   130 |
+-------+-------+--------+-----------+---------------+---------------------+------------------+-----------------+------------+-------+
```

Comment: [Why not to use images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: [How to ask a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question)

Comment: [Why to provide a MRE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Warrenk: it seems you have a real question here, but it's very hard to understand what you're asking.

Comment: The challenge is the logic to drive out partitions and orders. We have to find the first level earliest transactions that contain a transfer or switch and then order the subsequent child transactions before moving to the next first level transaction.

Comment: @RossPresser Could you please reopen this question as I have added details and desired output?

Comment: @warrenk ok, I voted to reopen. (I'm not the only one who voted to close, and it takes more than just me to reopen.)